# WiFi Protected Setup (WPS) code in iOS

Tags: ios, wifi

I was wondering if anyone know if it is possible to create an application to connect your iPhone/iPad to a router via WiFi Protected Setup (WPS).

I know applications in Windows and Linux that can connect using this protocol, so the question is if it is possible to code an application in iOS, or, at least, port a linux app to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access WiFi settings from any App for security reasons.

See for more info: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/is-it-possible-to-connect-an-iphone-ipad-via-wifi-protected-setup-wps

Comment: Well, I know you can't connect a iDevice using WPS, but is it possible to code it? I have search the web and find some solutions in GitHub for Linux and Java, some of them said you have to use libpcap and libssl. I know these both, and the main problem I find is the impossibility of iDevices for read packages without a network connection.

Comment: For what i know you cant access WiFi and most of the system settings for security reasons. So the answer is no.